# The MARS TDS header contained errors - ASP.NET Core + EF Core 2.1.4 + Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-core

I have an ASP.NET Core app [Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.4] with EF Core 2.1.4 [DbContext pooling enabled] and data stored on an Azure SQL database.

Occasinaly [once in 1-2 days] I get unrecoverable error stating System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) protocol stream is incorrect. The MARS TDS header contained errors.

Once I restart the app, everything resumes working until it happens again.

Probably import to note is that I don't have MultipleActiveResultSets enabled in my connection string at all, which makes the issue even more strange.

Has anyone else noticed something similar? Are there any ways I can trace the problem?

Stack trace:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) protocol stream is incorrect. The MARS TDS header contained errors.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementation[TState,TResult](Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded, TState state)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Inviton.Web.Portal.Controllers.EventListController.GetEvents(BL bl, Int32 venueId, Int32 promoterId) 
   ---snip---
```

Comment: Could you please add the following to your connection string: MultipleActiveResultSets=False

Comment: Please query the following DMV (SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_connections) you will get surprised seen some connections using MARS.

Comment: Hi Alberto, I've already explicitly set the MultipleActiveResultSets=False, but still the same.... I've executed the query you've suggested. Where can I see if the connection is using MARS please ?

Comment: Please refer to this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-connections-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017. Read documentation about columns "net_transport" and "parent_connection_id"

Comment: This is what I'm receiving https://az687816.vo.msecnd.net/imgstore/QhCMEpiLUx_FNXWJ33DN4XRZVZ3CVNW636747667826782576.jpg

Based on the description in the docs I'd assume none of the connection is using MARS at the moment, am I right?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: The issue however appeared again just a couple of minutes ago. Again, restarting the server solved the issue...is there any way for me to trace what was happening with the server prior to the problem occurence?

Comment: If you are talking about the Azure SQL Database https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-xevent-code-event-file

Comment: For your application, you may want to enable logging https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log

Comment: I hope these 2 give you a better chance to identify the issue.

Comment: I'm getting the same error in last few days. Also MARS disabled, but we are not using EF - we just use Dapper in .NET framework app. I noticed that update "2018-10 Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2016 for x64-based Systems (KB4462917)" was installed on that machine on the day when it started, so I'm suspecting that it could be caused by that update. Can you check if it's installed on your machine?

Comment: As we are hosted on Azure SQL I'm not sure how to do that. Any hint on how can I find out?

Comment: I meant to check it on the machine that connects to the SQL database, not on database server (Azure SQL). But if you host it as a web app, you will probably not be able to check it...

Comment: We are hosted on Azure App service, I've tried to check using the console and dism command, I'm however lacking sufficient privilleges to do so..

Comment: We're having the same issue. Might be related: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/32752

Comment: @bruno-laurinec could you maybe share the code for the workaround u've done

Answer (score 3):

For all the ones who are still facing this problem and ends up on this page.

There's a open issue on SqlCLient https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/85

As of today is not fixed.

But there's a hackaroud which mitigate it https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/85#issuecomment-469432914

Comment: Fixed in SqlClient version 1.1.2 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/1.1.2) released on April 15

Comment: @Calax that's Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, the OP is using System.Data.SqlClient.

Comment: According to https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/85, System.Data.SqlClient is fixed as of version 4.8.2

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Right Click your Project -> Manage nuget packages -> Updates.

Update Microsoft.Data.SqlClient to last version.

Comment: The OP is using System.Data.SqlClient, not Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.

Comment: you're right and haven't noticed. I landed here via google so this might be helpful  for someone else with my same problem