# The incoming TDS protocol stream is incorrect' error requiring IIS restart

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, sql-server-2014

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 2.0.8 application, and it has been running smoothly. However, I'm facing an intermittent issue with all of my APIs. Occasionally, when I call this API, it returns an error, and the only way to resolve it is by restarting IIS.

Here's the error message I'm encountering:

> {
> "errors": [
> "The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) protocol stream is incorrect. The MARS TDS header contained errors."
> ]
> }

Has anyone else experienced this error with ASP.NET Core? I've already set MultipleActiveResultSets=False;and MultipleActiveResultSets=True; in my web.config, but the issue persists.

**Configuration and Environment:**

- ASP.NET Core version: 2.0.8
- Operating System: Windows Server 2016
- IIS version: 10
- SQL Server: Microsoft SQL Server 2014
- Connection string in web.config: **MultipleActiveResultSets=False;**

**
Troubleshooting Steps:**

I've checked my SQL Server configuration to ensure that MARS is enabled     client side.
I've reviewed my connection strings to ensure **MultipleActiveResultSets** is set to False.
The error seems to occur intermittently, and it's challenging to predict when it will happen.
I'd appreciate any insights, suggestions, or solutions to resolve this issue and prevent the need to restart IIS.

**What I Tried:**
I've thoroughly reviewed my code, ensured that my SQL Server configuration has MARS enabled, and set MultipleActiveResultSets to False anf true also  in my connection strings. Additionally, I've checked for any potential memory leaks in the API that could be causing this issue. However, despite these efforts, the problem still occurs intermittently.

**Expected Outcome:**
I expected that setting MultipleActiveResultSets to False and verifying the SQL Server configuration would prevent the 'TDS protocol stream is incorrect' error. My expectation was that this change should resolve the issue.

**Actual Result:**
The problem still persists, and I continue to encounter the error sporadically. This is quite frustrating as I have not been able to pinpoint the exact cause of the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "ensured that my SQL Server configuration has MARS enabled"? AFAIK, MARS is controlled by the client connection string. Are you using `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` or `System.Data.SqlClient`?

Comment: There's no such version as .NET Core 2.8 - what version did you mean? 2.0.8?

Comment: i am using entity frame work . and some contoller are using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.
MultipleActiveResultSets  i check with false also and true also 

ensured that my SQL Server configuration has MARS enabled" that i find somere help to do but not found there .i will edit question also .

Comment: yes 2.0.8  sorry for confusing

Comment: *"SQL Server: Microsoft SQL Server 2019"* Why have you tagged [[tag:sql-server-2012]] then? Is it 2012 (which is completely unsupported) or 2019?

Comment: i did find 2019 in tag .

Comment: Ok, so why tag 2012? If you found the 2019 tag, and you are using 2019, why tag 2012? Like I asked, are you *actually* using 2012? [Edit] the question to correct it appropriately.

Comment: ok i am editing .its my first time question sorry for that

Comment: Without the code, actual error and NuGet package versions, the only thing one can say is that .NET Core 2.x is out of support for quite some time now. The oldest supported version is .NET 6. It's quite possible you're using obsolete versions of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient,

Comment: [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52726258/the-mars-tds-header-contained-errors-asp-net-core-ef-core-2-1-4-azure-sql) may be a duplicate of this one, if you use an old version of either Microsoft.Data.SqlClient or System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: Also are you on the latest build of SQL Server 2019?